# Django Adding Prefix to FileField

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that takes in multiple pdf files.  When users upload these files, I'd like each file to be renamed with a prefix and some random characters.  I can assign the upload_to to callable functions, example:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    invoice_file = models.FileField(upload_to=invoice_file_name)
    purchase_order_file = models.FileField( upload_to=po_file_name)
    payment_file = models.FileField( upload_to=payment_file_name)

def invoice_file_name(instance, file_name):
    return 'inv_' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.pdf'

def po_file_name(instance, file_name):
    return 'po_' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.pdf'

def payment_file_name(instance, file_name):
    return 'pmt_' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.pdf'
```

Is there a way to generalize these upload_to functions so I can pass the prefix in the FileField definition?

**ATTEMPT:**

I attempted to solve this by creating a custom file field that extends FileField

```
class CustomFileField(models.FileField):
    def __init__(self, file_prefix, **kwargs):
        self.file_prefix = file_prefix
        # print(kwargs)
        super().__init__(upload_to=self.custom_upload_to, **kwargs)

    def custom_upload_to(self, file_name):
        return self.file_prefix + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.pdf' 


class Order(models.Model):
    invoice_file = CustomFileField(file_prefix='inv_')
    purchase_order_file = CustomFileField(file_prefix='po_')
    payment_file = CustomFileField(file_prefix='pmt_')
```

However, the migrations failed.  One of the errors is

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'upload_to'
```

Not quite sure what's going on but I looked at the migration file and it seems to be calling this:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
    name='Order',
    fields=[
        ('invoice_file', CustomFileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='')
        ...
    ])
```

Is this the wrong way to subclass FileField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it without `CustomFileField` but rather with `@deconstructible`

```
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from django.db import models


@deconstructible
class file_prefix(object):
    def __init__(self, prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1] # PDF if you want
        filename = "%s%s.%s" % (self.prefix,str(uuid.uuid4()), ext)
        return filename
```

instance, filename are sent by default when calling `upload_to`, so we just send the prefix.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    invoice_file = models.FileField(upload_to=file_prefix('inv_'))
    purchase_order_file = models.FileField(upload_to=file_prefix('po_'))
    payment_file = models.FileField(upload_to=file_prefix('pmt_'))
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what @deconstructible does, but this works.  No issue with the migration

Comment: More info --> [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#adding-a-deconstruct-method)

Answer (score 1):

This is what works:

```
class CustomFileField(models.FileField):
    def __init__(self, file_prefix = '', null=True, blank=True, upload_to='', **kwargs):
        self.file_prefix = file_prefix
        super().__init__(upload_to=self.custom_upload_to, **kwargs)

    def custom_upload_to(self, instance, file_name):
        return self.file_prefix + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.pdf' 


class Order(models.Model):
    invoice_file = CustomFileField(file_prefix='inv_')
    purchase_order_file = CustomFileField(file_prefix='po_')
    payment_file = CustomFileField(file_prefix='pmt_')
```

It seems that the migration serializer looks for 3 parameters: null, blank and upload_to, so I need to have these parameters in my CustomFileField init function.

Comment: This does not work in DRF, it keeps create migration steps